# Can anyone help me with confusion about the definition of gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

(From Introduction to Riemannian Manifold by Lee, problem 8-2)

Let $(M, g)$ be an embedded Riemannian hypersurface in a Riemannian manifold $(N, h)$, and let $F$ be a local defining function for $M$, and let $\nu = grad\, F/|grad\, F|$.

What I am confused here is that $F$ is a function that takes $p \in M$ to some $F(p) \in N$, and grad $F$ cannot be well-defined. Can anyone explain why $\nu$ is a normal to local embedding $F(M)$?

edit: Or perhaps, $F: N \rightarrow \mathbb R$, and $M = \{F=c\}$?

Comment: Your first description of $F$ is wrong, the description in your "edit" is correct.

Comment: @LeeMosher is correct. I'll just add that the term _**local defining function**_ is defined at the bottom of page 380. See also the middle of page 248.